# animate() not working continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate `#ani` continuously using `animate()` in jQuery. My code only works one time. How do I make this animation loop?

Here is my code, and you can see an online demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9hN2g/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="ani">animation</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#ani').css('position','absolute');

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ani').animate({top:'-10px'},2000)
},100);

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ani').animate({top:'20px'},2000)
},100);
```

Comment: No one of the provided answer was worth your comment or a vote?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#ani').css('position','absolute');
function loop(){
    $('#ani').animate({top:'-10px'},2000,function(){
        $('#ani').animate({top:'20px'},2000,function(){
               loop();            
        }) ;                
    })    

}
loop()
```

I think you can see the modified online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9hN2g/5/

Comment: Please always post code in your answer - just in case jsfiddle is down or deletes your link.

Comment: Presumably in your simple case you can just pass `loop` itself to the nested `animate` call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setInterval()`, not `setTimeout()`, and call the second part of the animation as the callback of the first. Try this:

```
function animate() {
    $('#ani').stop(true, true).animate({ top: '-10px' }, 1000, function() {
        $('#ani').stop(true, true).animate({ top: '20px' }, 1000)
    })
}

animate(); // on load
setInterval(animate, 2000); // set to run continously
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hN2g/6/)

Comment: By default animations on the same element run in queue, so: `$('#ani').stop(true, true).animate({ top: '-10px' }, 1000).animate({ top: '20px' }, 1000);` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

What your current code is saying is that:

1. One tenth of a second from now (`100ms`), start a 2 second animation moving `#ani` to -10px.
2. At that exact same time (another `100ms`), start another 2 second animation moving `#ani` to 20px.

What jQuery does here is to queue the second animation. Your code could be written as:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ani').animate({top:'-10px'}).animate({top:'20px'}),2000);
},100);
```

What you'd need for a continuous animation is to use `callbacks`; a function to call when the animation completes.

```
function moveUp() {
   $('#ani').animate({ top: -10 }, 2000, moveDown);
}

function moveDown() {
   $('#ani').animate({ top: 20 }, 2000, moveUp);
}

setTimeout(moveUp, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

make your functions recursive.

```
$('#ani').css('position', 'absolute');
anim1();
function anim1() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#ani').animate({
            top: '-10px'
        }, 2000, function(){
            anim2();
        });
    }, 100);
}

function anim2() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#ani').animate({
            top: '20px'
        }, 2000, function(){
            anim1();
        });
    }, 100);
}​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9hN2g/7/)

Answer (score 0):

see this once http://jsfiddle.net/9hN2g/8/, just replace setTimeout() function with setInterval() . 
go through this link once for better understanding diff b/w these two fun's http://www.whadiz.com/what-is.aspx/programming/javascript/settimeout-versus-setinterval

```
$('#ani').css('position','absolute');

setInterval(function(){
    $('#ani').animate({top:'-10px'},2000)
},100);

setInterval(function(){
    $('#ani').animate({top:'20px'},2000)
},100);
```